# Effect of a photon on curvature of spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, photons, spacetime

Since light [has no rest mass](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/ParticleAndNuclear/photon_mass.html), is it reasonable to assume that the curvature of spacetime is not affected (distorted) by a single photon?

Sure, a photon is attracted due to gravity. But could be something attracted by a photon?

Comment: Related (possible dupe) http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70993/

Comment: Energy and curvature http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186414/